# Sending single email with 3 different attachments python 3

Tags: python, email-attachments

I'm just looking to send an email with 3 csv file attachments.  When i get it to run, trying a solution i found on here, it gives me a BIN file instead of the 3 files. Or, trying another solution, it will only send the last of the the 3 files.  When i run the code below, its gives me TypeError: add.header() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given.

I understand that it can be done with a function, but i'm not sure how to have it pull all three files into it. I've spent numerous hours trying to figure it out.

Posting it on here is my last resort. I appreciate any help in finding a solution.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import time
import os

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = EMAIL_FROM
msg['To'] = ", ".join(RECIPIENT_LIST)
msg['Subject'] = 'Louisiana Contractors List'

#email content
message = """<html>
<body>
Attached is the Louisiana Contractors Spreadsheet.
<br><br>

Let me know if you have any questions

</body>
</html>
"""

msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'html'))

files = [
    'C:/Users/rkrouse/Downloads/search-results.csv',
    'C:/Users/rkrouse/Downloads/search-results(1).csv',
    'C:/Users/rkrouse/Downloads/search-results(2).csv']

for a_file in files:
    attachment = open(a_file, 'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', a_file = os.path.basename('C:/Users/rkrouse/Downloads/search-results.csv'))
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    msg.attach(part)

for a_file in files:
    attachment = open(a_file, 'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', a_file = os.path.basename('C:/Users/rkrouse/Downloads/search-results(1).csv'))
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    msg.attach(part)

for a_file in files:
    attachment = open(a_file, 'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload(attachment.read())
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', a_file = os.path.basename('C:/Users/rkrouse/Downloads/search-results(2).csv'))
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    msg.attach(part)

#sends email
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP(EMAIL_SERVER, EMAIL_PORT)
smtpserver.sendmail(EMAIL_FROM, RECIPIENT_LIST, msg.as_string())
smtpserver.quit()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated tested solution:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import time
import os

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = EMAIL_FROM
msg['To'] = ", ".join(RECIPIENT_LIST)
msg['Subject'] = 'Louisiana Contractors List'

#email content
message = """<html>
<body>
Attached is the Louisiana Contractors Spreadsheet.
<br><br>

Let me know if you have any questions

</body>
</html>
"""

msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'html'))

files = [
    'C:/Users/rkrouse/Downloads/search-results.csv',
    'C:/Users/rkrouse/Downloads/search-results(1).csv',
    'C:/Users/rkrouse/Downloads/search-results(2).csv']

for a_file in files:
    attachment = open(a_file, 'rb')
    file_name = os.path.basename(a_file)
    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload(attachment.read())
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                    'attachment',
                    filename=file_name)
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    msg.attach(part)

#sends email

smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP(EMAIL_SERVER, EMAIL_PORT)
smtpserver.sendmail(EMAIL_FROM, RECIPIENT_LIST, msg.as_string())
smtpserver.quit()
```

As you can see you need to specify the filename in the base64 encoding. 
Also you are iterating the files three time.

A `for` loop is used to go through a list, set, array, etc. One for loop (as all attachments are in one list) should be enough.

Comment: do i add the r'C:\users\yada\downloads\searc-results.csv' in place of a_file through out the function (even the for a_file in files) or just within the function?

Comment: Honestly it would be better to use the variable and insert the attachments to an email function. This way you can later reuse the code.

Comment: this is what i used and it gives me a TypeError: sequence item0: expected str instance, _io.Buffered Reader found for a_file in files:
    attachment = open(a_file, 'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', attachment, a_file=r'C:\Users\rkrouse\Downloads\search-results.csv')
    msg.attach(part)

Comment: the attachement in app_header should be a string... I'll edit the above

Comment: it's now generating the email, but it's shooting out .bin files instead of the actual attachments.  Is it because i'm using the full path name? Any idea why?!

Comment: That's correct I normally would use os.path.basename(a_path) in the add_header. Without actually running this you could try to remove the parenthesis around attachment in the set payload: part.set_payload(attachment.read())  I'll edit this in as well

Comment: so, it's still sending .bin files.  3 for each attachment.  i tried, separately, the (attachment.read()), the os.path.basename.  Then i tried them together and i'm still getting the .bin files.  Here's that line for the os.path.basename     part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', a_file = os.path.basename('C:/Users/rkrouse/Downloads/search-results(1).csv'))

Comment: btw, i really appreciate you helping me with this.  I've learned so much just from going through this.

Comment: I've  checked my own library and realized that the payload needed encoding. I've added it to the solution.

Comment: sorry about that, i had added that as part of your previous suggestion.  encoders.encode_base64(part) I think the python gods are against me today.  :-/ i'm going to update the code i have to this point.  Maybe there's something i haven't mentioned in our conversation.

Comment: I've updated the code from you new submitted code. Except for the missing mail server details this should work.

Comment: that worked!!  so, once the global variable 'files' was created, you then have to create a variable for it just for the loop?  am i understanding that correctly?

Comment: The global variable 'files' is actually a list. This does not have to be a global variable as it can be a list inside a definition as well. to further use the items in a list you will need to assign them to a variable enabling them to be used. I would suggest to read up on for loops as the are very common and useful.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the simple snippet that I used to send an email to multiple people with multiple file attachments.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import smtplib
import mimetypes
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email import encoders
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import ntpath

sender_address = 'vijay.anand@xxxx.com'
default_subject = 'Test email from {}'.format(sender_address)
smtp_server_address = '10.111.41.25'
smtp_port_number = 25

default_message = message = """<html>
<body>
Attached is the Louisiana Contractors Spreadsheet.
<br><br>

Let me know if you have any questions

</body>
</html>
"""


def send_by_smtp(to=None, cc=None, bcc=None, subject=None, attachments=None, attachment_type='plain'):
    """
        Snippet to send an email to multiple people along with multiple attachments.
        :param to: list of emails
        :param cc: list of emails
        :param bcc: list of emails
        :param subject: Email Subject
        :param attachments: list of file paths
        :param attachment_type: 'plain' or 'html'
        :return: None
    """
    email_from = sender_address
    email_to = list()
    files_to_send = attachments
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg["From"] = email_from
    if to:
        to = list(set(to))
        email_to += to
        msg["To"] = ', '.join(to)
    if cc:
        cc = list(set(cc))
        email_to += cc
        msg["Cc"] = ', '.join(cc)
    if bcc:
        bcc = list(set(bcc))
        email_to += bcc
        msg["Bcc"] = ', '.join(bcc)
    if subject:
        msg["Subject"] = subject
        msg.preamble = subject
    else:
        msg["Subject"] = default_subject
        msg.preamble = default_subject

    body = default_message
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, attachment_type))

    if files_to_send:
        for file_to_send in files_to_send:
            content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file_to_send)
            if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
                content_type = "application/octet-stream"
            maintype, subtype = content_type.split("/", 1)
            if maintype == "text":
                with open(file_to_send) as fp:
                    # Note: we should handle calculating the charset
                    attachment = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
            elif maintype == "image":
                with open(file_to_send, "rb") as fp:
                    attachment = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
            elif maintype == "audio":
                with open(file_to_send, "rb")as fp:
                    attachment = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
            else:
                with open(file_to_send, "rb") as fp:
                    attachment = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
                    attachment.set_payload(fp.read())
                encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
            attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=ntpath.basename(file_to_send))
            msg.attach(attachment)

    try:
        smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP(host=smtp_server_address, port=smtp_port_number, timeout=300)
        smtp_obj.sendmail(from_addr=email_from, to_addrs=list(set([email_from] + email_to)), msg=msg.as_string())
        print("Successfully sent email to {}".format(str(email_to)))
        smtp_obj.quit()
        return True
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
        print("Error: unable to send email")
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Send an email using Python')
    result = send_by_smtp(to=['vijay@xxxx.com', 'tha@xxx.com'],
                          cc=['anandp@xxxx.com', 'nitha@xxxx.com'],
                          bcc=['vij@xxxx.com', 'Sun@xxxx.com'],
                          subject='Louisiana Contractors List',
                          attachments=['test.txt', '1.JPG', '2.PNG', '3.PNG', '4.PNG'],
                          attachment_type='html')
    if result:
        print('Email Sent Successfully')
    else:
        print('Email Sending Failed')
```